# how to test the DLX on RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I am trying to set up DLX, ideally 1 for each queue. I want to migrate 5 jobs but starting with one.

I ran this line which will apply to all queues but I am not sure how to select a specific queue `rabbitmqctl set_policy DLX ".*" '{"dead-letter-exchange":"all-dlx"}' --apply-to queues`.

I have the following code the send to the queue

```
$this->channel->exchange_declare('all-dlx', 'fanout', false, true);
    $args = [
        'x-dead-letter-exchange'=> 'all-dlx'
    ];
    $this->channel->exchange_declare($exchange, 'direct', false, true, false, false, $args);
    //$this->channel->queue_declare($queueName, false, true, false, false, $args);
    //$this->channel->exchange_declare($queueName, 'fanout', false, false, false);

    $msg = new AMQPMessage($body
        ,array('delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT)
    );

    //$this->channel->basic_publish($msg, '', $queueName);
    $this->channel->basic_publish($msg, $exchange);
```

I am forcing a failure to test the DLX.

```
$this->channel->queue_declare($queueName, false, true, false, false);
    //$this->channel->exchange_declare($queueName, 'fanout', false, false, false);
    //list($queue_name, ,) = $this->channel->queue_declare("");
    $this->channel->queue_bind($queueName, 'cm_upload');

    $this->channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
    $this->channel->basic_consume($queueName, '', false, false, false, false, $callback);

    //$this->channel->basic_consume($queue_name, '', false, false, false, false, $callback);

    while ($this->channel->is_consuming()) {
        try {
            $this->channel->wait();
            $this->log->debug("waiting...");
        } catch (\ErrorException $e) {
            $this->log->error($e);
        }
    }
```

How can I tell if it has actually gone to the DLX and the contents of the DLX? I am using php

[image: queues]

[image: detail queue]

**UPDATE**

Shall I do it like this. so each queue will have a DLX queue where the dlx queue is bound to the dlx-exchange?

```
$this->channel->exchange_declare('all-dlx', 'fanout', false, true);
        $args = [
            'x-dead-letter-exchange'=> 'all-dlx'
        ];
        $this->channel->exchange_declare($exchange, 'direct', false, true, false, false, $args);
        $this->channel->queue_declare($queueName, false, true, false, false, $args);

        // declare dlx for queue
        $this->channel->queue_declare("dlx-$queueName", false, true, false, false);
        $this->channel->queue_bind("dlx-$queueName", 'all-dlx');
```

How would I tell the task which dlx queue it is meant to fail to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other exchange, a [Dead Letter Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) doesn't *contain* messages, it *routes* them. In fact, the exchange doesn't even know it's a DLX, it just receives messages; the DLX setting just tells the queue *where to send* undelivered messages.

So to confirm that your configuration is working:

1. Create the `all-dlx` exchange as a "fanout" exchange. It doesn't need any special parameters.
2. Create a queue like `dlx-test-queue`.
3. Create a binding from `all-dlx` to `dlx-test-queue`.
4. Configure a queue to use your new exchange as its DLX; by passing the `'x-dead-letter-exchange'` argument to `queue_declare`, or setting a policy as you show in your question.
5. Force a failure, e.g. by calling `basic_nack` instead of `basic_ack` in your consumer code.
6. The message should be re-delivered to the `all-dlx` exchange, and routed to the `dlx-test-queue`, which you can verify by looking at the number of messages in that queue in the admin console.

Comment: If I create a queue for it, will the messages remain indefinitely? this is what I want unless I manually delete them

Comment: I passed the args to the exchange? is that normal?

Comment: @shorif2000 The queue is just a normal queue; messages will stay there just as long as they would in any other queue. Passing the `x-dead-letter-exchange` argument to an exchange _won't do anything_; it never has any "dead letters" to re-publish. (The closest equivalent is messages not routed to any queue, for which there is a separate concept of [Alternate Exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html)).

Comment: a) You're still passing the `x-dead-letter-exchange` argument to `exchange_declare`; you don't need to do that. b) What exchanges and queues you create is completely up to you - again, these are just _normal exchanges_ and _normal queues_; the DLX setting is just a special way of connecting them together. c) This isn't a forum, so going back and forth over different examples discussing different parts of them isn't going to fit the site format; if there's something you don't understand in my answer, I'll edit it, but if you just have new questions, ask them on new pages.